# Why does my outlook reminder not update when I move a meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reminder

Sometimes, when I move a meeting in my outlook calendar I still get a reminder for the initial time.

So, if I have a meeting at 9:00 and I move it till 12:00, I still get a reminder at 8:45.

**EDIT:** You have different types of notifications. I am now talking about the notification that pops up in the task bar, not the notification that Outlook is providing me (when Outlook is running). Hope that helps!

Also, it happend once with a meeting that had been removed from my calendar all together!

Comment: Does this issue affect all meetings or only occur to some particular meetings? Have you sent out the update for the meeting to change the time?

Comment: I happens when I schedule a meeting and then change the time of the meeting. Funny thing is, it doesn't always occur, which make debugging quite the challenge...

Answer (score 0):

For my particular instance of this issue, closing out of outlook and then opening it from Run with `outlook /cleanreminders` allowed my reminders to update correctly again when I move meetings.

I got the idea from https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/outlook-errors/fix-outlook-reminder-is-not-working.html.